# Survey to determine satisfaction: how to find the questions that mattered?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

If a survey is given to determine overall customer satisfaction, and there are 20 general questions and a final summary question: "What's your overall satisfaction 1-10", how could it be determined which questions are most significantly related to the summary question's answer?

In short, which questions actually mattered and which ones were just wasting space on the survey...

Comment: I think this question is better suited to [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com). Many of the users there analyze surveys for a living!  (It's a good question, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about the relevance of certain features is given by linear classification and regression weights associated with these features.

For your specific application, you could try training an L1 or L0 regularized regressor (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-angle_regression, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pursuit). These regularizers force many of the regression weights to zero, which means that the features associated with these weights can be effectively ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different approaches for answering this question and at varying levels of sophistication.  I would start by calculating the correlation matrix for all pair-wise combinations of answers, thereby indicating which individual questions are most (or most negatively) correlated with the overall satisfaction score. This is pretty straightforward in Excel with [the Analysis ToolPak.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff969363.aspx)

Next, I would look into clustering techniques starting simple and moving up in sophistication only if necessary.  Not knowing anything about the domain to which this survey data applies it is hard to say which algorithm would be the most effective, but for starters I would look at k-means and variants if your clusters are likely to all be similarly-sized.  However, if a vast majority of the responses are very similar, I would look into expectation-maximization-based algorithms.  A good open-source toolkit for exploring data and testing the efficacy of various algorithms is called [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).